# How to get KeyMap keydown event on grid panel with paging toolbar

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to get a keydown event working on my gridpanel with pagingtoolbar so that when you hold the up or down arrow keys it carries on through the pages without need for stopping or repetitive key presses. This process works on the keyup event but I have not managed to get it to recognise keydown events.

My code is as current:

Grid:

```
trackGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        layout: 'fit',
        autoSizeColumns:false,
        autoHeight:true,
        maxHeight:400,
        frame:true,
        trackMouseOver:true,
        selModel: Ext.create("Ext.selection.RowModel"),
        store: TrackPaged,
        columns:[
            {header: 'Time', width:55, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'time'},
            {header: 'Speed', width:50, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'speed', renderer: this.renderTrackSpeed},
            {header: 'Dirn', width:50, sortable:true, dataIndex: 'hdg', tooltip: 'Direction of travel'},
            {header: 'ECode', width:70, sortable:true, dataIndex: 'event', renderer: this.renderTrackEvent, tooltip: 'Event Code'},
            {header: 'Status', width:50, sortable:true, dataIndex: 'sts'},
            {header: 'id', width:50, sortable:true, dataIndex: 'lid', hidden: true}
        ],
        viewConfig:{
            forceFit:true,
            EnableRowBody:true,
            showPreview:false
        },
        bbar:trackPagedToolbar,
        footerCfg:{
            html:'<div id="track-info" class="grid-info"><p>No events to display</p></div>'
        }
    });
```

My KeyMaps:

```
trackGrid.getEl().set({tabindex: "0"})

    trackGrid.getEl().addKeyMap({
        eventName: "keyup",
        binding: [{
            key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
            fn: function() {
                this.selectTrackMarkerInfo();
            }
        }, {
        key: [Ext.EventObject.RIGHT, Ext.EventObject.PAGE_DOWN],
        fn:  function(){ 
            trackPagedToolbar.moveNext();
                    trackGrid.getSelectionModel().select(0); 
        }
        },{
        key: [Ext.EventObject.LEFT, Ext.EventObject.PAGE_UP],
        fn: function(){ 
            trackPagedToolbar.movePrevious();
                    trackGrid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        }
        }, {
            key: Ext.EventObject.HOME,
            fn: function() {
                trackPagedToolbar.moveFirst();
                    trackGrid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            }
        }, {
            key: Ext.EventObject.END,
            fn: function() {
                trackPagedToolbar.moveLast();
                    trackGrid.getSelectionModel().select(TrackPaged.getCount()-1);
            }
        }]
    });

    trackGrid.getEl().addKeyMap({
        eventName: 'itemkeydown',
        binding: [{
        key: Ext.EventObject.DOWN,
        fn: function() {
            if (trackGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].index % 14 == 13) {
                trackPagedToolbar.moveNext();
                trackGrid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            }
        }
    }, {
        key: Ext.EventObject.UP,
        fn: function() {
            if (trackGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0] = 0) {
                trackPagedToolbar.movePrevious();
                trackGrid.getSelectionModel().select(13);
            }
        }
    }]
    });
```

From the documentation on the KeyMap I have unsuccessfully tried to specifically add the target of trackGrid, and change the event to 'itemkeydown', 'keydown', and 'keypress'. None of which have even registered when I hold either key down.

Does anyone have any insight on the matter?